# I have edited UIImagePickerController.h by mistake . now i am getting errors in my project as below

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios-simulator

`UIKit.framework/Headers/UIImagePickerController.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users / Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2gh/UIKit.pcm'` was built.

I also got

```
"
    note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2PG1NJRUR3TN0'
```

1 error generated.

"
I restarted my xcode5 , but it is not working.

Comment: May be you make speling mistack in it...please make sure that you .h filename and .M name would be same.

Comment: This is why you should use a source control system, fortunately for you others do.  https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UIImagePickerController.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a final rescue, i reinstalled xcode.It always works...

Answer (score 4):

> In Your /Users/dipenchudasama/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
>   delete all contain from here and also restart your XCODE surely this
>   wwill working.