# Xcode crashes when i run the app on my real device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I joined the apple iOS developer program and registered my iPhone 5 with the unique UDID.
I registered my Xcode app at the "APP ID" section and made a development profile and added it to the "provisioning profile".

When I run the app on my iPhone - it does't install/run on my iPhone and the Xcode crashes.

What can I do to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: you try to remove derived data...?

Comment: see my answer here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137003/i-have-edited-uiimagepickercontroller-h-by-mistake-now-i-am-getting-errors-in/19137186#19137186

Comment: @DipenChudasama Ok I did it now, still doesn't work! what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in xcode that made it crash when you hit build and run in fullscreen. Maybe try `cmd + r` instead.